# Is the magnitude of a product of complex numbers equal to the magnitude of its components?

Tags: complex-numbers

Reading a book  "Microwave engineering" by Pozar page 560, 4th ed and the author uses formulas
like $|abc|= |a|\cdot|b|\cdot|c|$, how can it be proven that this is correct?

Further more, could someone please check my sanity regarding a result where the author arrives
at $=\frac{|V_1^+|^2}{2Z_0}(1-|\Gamma_{in}|^2)$ when he according to my understanding apparently has calculated (not shown by the author)
$$P_{in}=\frac{1}{2Z_0}V_1^+V_1^{+*}(1+\Gamma_{in})(1+\Gamma_{in})^*\\
       =\frac{|V_1^+|^2}{2Z_0}(1+\Gamma_{in})(1+\Gamma_{in}^*)\\
       =\frac{|V_1^+|^2}{2Z_0}(1+|\Gamma_{in}|^2)\\$$
What am I missing? If I am correct about the path the author has taken, am I correct or is the author or are we both wrong?

Comment: These formulas can be proven by writing $a=x+iy$ and $b=u+iv$ ($x,y,u,v$ real) and using the rules of complex number multiplication and magnitude (modulus) calculation. A handy rule is $|a|^2=aa^*$. What is $\Gamma_{in}$ ?

Comment: Modulus is stable by multiplication, its elementary by just checking it for any complex numbers.

Comment: @KurtG. $\Gamma_{in}=S_{11} +\frac{S_{12} S_{21}\Gamma_L}{1 - S_{22}\Gamma_L}$ where all terms on RHS are complex. S-numbers are scattering parameters. $\Gamma_{in}$ reflection coeff. looking into the network. $\Gamma_L$ reflection at the load on the other side of the network

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As to |abc|=|a||b||c|  you just verify it for |ab|=|a||b| by calculating both sides a=a+ib, b=x+iy
2. The result you deduct is wrong, since $(1+z)*(1+\bar{z})\neq  1+|z|^2$  and $\bar{1+z}\neq 1+\bar{z}$ supposing the star means the conjugate?

Comment: I can see cases where $(1+z)(1+\bar{z})=1+|z|^2$ which is why I asked OP what $\Gamma_{in}$ is .

Comment: $\Gamma_{in}$ is always a complex number with both a real and an imaginary part which comes from the fact that loads which is attached to the transistors are real Ohms(resistors) with unwanted imaginary part from stray inductances and stray capacitances.

Answer (score 3):

> $|abc|=|a|⋅|b|⋅|c|$, how can it be proven that this is correct?

It is enough to show that $|ab|=|a||b|$ which is equivalent to $|ab|^2=|a|^2|b|^2$ because the absolute value is non-negative. Finally,$$|ab|^2=ab\,\overline{ab}=a\overline a\,b\overline b = |a|^2|b|^2$$

> $(1+Γ_\text{in})(1+Γ^∗_\text{in})$

$$(1+Γ)(1+Γ^*)=1+Γ+Γ^*+ΓΓ^* = 1+2\operatorname{Re}(Γ) + |Γ|^2$$

which in general is not equal to $1-|Γ|^2$.